# EF Core implementing Table-Per-Concrete-Type with fluent mapping of abstract base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Suppose that you have two entities derived from an abstract base class and you want implement Table-Per-Concrete-Type. Entities like below:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

   public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Person : EntityBase
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class PersonStatus : EntityBase
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And you don’t want to use attribute in the abstract base class(EntityBase), you want to map EntityBase class in dbcontext *only once* for all entities. How to change the code below :

```
public class PeopleDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      // Entity base class mapping(only once)

      modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(e =>
      {
        e.Property(x => x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
      });
      modelBuilder.Entity<PersonStatus>(e =>
      {
        e.Property(x => x.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? I have setups like this and the Id is picked up by convention.

Comment: Yes, when i tried to map(fluent) EntityBase class in dbcontext, ef created another table for EntityBase class. Before this, I implemented with fluent nhibernate and that worked properly with using  ClassMap.
Also, i used ef 6 “builder.Types<EntityBase>(..)”. It worked as i want. But with ef core i couldn’t make it.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943048/ef-core-fluent-api-set-all-column-types-of-interface/45944872?noredirect=1) is an answer to your question..

You need to write Configurations for your BaseClass:

```
public class EntityBaseConfiguration<TBase> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TBase>
    where TBase : EntityBase
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBase> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.Property(b => b.CreatedBy)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
        builder.Property(b => b.CreatedAt)
            .HasColumnType("datetime2");
    }
}
```

After that, you can write your concrete Configuration-Class foreach Table which inherits from EntityBase like so:

```
public class PersonConfig : BaseConfig<Person>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
        builder.Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(100)")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

To invoke your configuration in your dbContext you can call ApplyConfiguration:

```
public class PeopleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PersonConfig());
    }
}
```