# Ef core fluent api set all column types of interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Unfortunately ef core does not support TPC-pattern, but we need this kind of behaviour. I´ve wrote an interface which is called IBase and each entity implements this interface:

```
public interface IBase
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    string CreateUser { get; set; }

    bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get rid of Annotations to use the Fluent API configuration instead. But I have about 20 different entities and 7 Base-Values and I don´t want to make the same configuration over and over again:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.CreateDate)
            .HasColumnType("datetime2(2)")
            .IsRequired();
```

Any ideas how to configure each Base-Property once for all entities implementing IBase?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EF core perfectly fine with base classes/inheritance, so just create an base generic class and put common things into it and then inherit your models from those base class like that:

```
public abstract class BaseModel<TId>
{
    TId Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    string CreateUser { get; set; }

    bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

class Model : BaseModel<Guid>{ ... //model specific stuff }
```

---

If for some reason it's deadly important for you to use fluentapi than there is a configuration interface exists called `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TModel>` and all what you need is again create base configuration and latter inherit specific configurations from it. And after that apply those configurations in your `DbContext.OnModelCreating` method somewhat like that:

```
class BaseConfiguration<TBaseModel> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TBaseModel>
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBaseModel> builder)
    {
        builder.Property...
    }
}

class ModelConfiguration : BaseConfiguration<Model>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Model> builder)
    {
         base.Configure(builder)
         ...// model specific stuff
    }
}

class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ModelConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your effort! But what about my "TPC"-Hint? Base class is not suitable for me, unless you can tell me, how I´m able to have all my base-values in every Database-Table. EF 6 provided 3 different patterns (TPH, TPC and TPT), ef core only supports TPH. So your answer is correct "in-content" but not really an answer to my question (until now)...

Comment: Try it first. It will create separate table for every concrete type. so It's TPC. 2nd - part with configuration have nothing related to model inheritance at all, it's about configuration inheritance so you could use interface or whatever.

Comment: I´m sorry!! I´ve tried it, and you are right - it works! But I want to be right at least one point.. ;) Your second claim is not correct - if I try to use an Interface for EntityTypeBuilder I get the following error: The entity type 'EfTEst.IBase' provided for the argument 'clrType' must be a reference type.

Comment: Well, this problem easily fixed with declaration like this: `BaseConfiguration<TBase> where TBase : class, IBase`

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for Entity Framework not Core:

```
        modelBuilder.Types<BaseModel>().Configure((configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.Property(p => p.CreateUser)
                .HasMaxLength(250)
                .IsRequired();
        });
```