# EF .net6 Migration "must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type."

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-6.0

So I'm trying to make migrate for my code,
I'm using C# and .Net 6 with clean architecture,
I have this in the "Core" solution:

> In Entities folder

```
public class Partenaire : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string? Telephone { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public string? ImmatriculeFiscale { get; set; }
    public string? NumeroRegistreCommerce { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IPartenaireContact> PartenaireContacts { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PartenaireActivite> PartenaireActivite { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PartenaireDetailsBancaire> PartenaireDetailsBancaires { get; set; }

}
```

In Entites/Base folder

```
public interface IPartenaireContact : IAuditableEntity, ISoftDelete
{
    public Guid PartenaireId { get; set; }
    public Partenaire Partenaire { get; set; }
}
```

So my Partenaire can have one or many PartenaireContact, the PartenaireContact in fact is inheriting from IdentityUser because the PartenaireContact is the user who can login in to the app

And in the "Infrastructure" solution:

> Data/identity folder

```
public class PartenaireContact : IdentityUser, IPartenaireContact
{
    public Guid PartenaireId { get; set; }
    public Partenaire Partenaire { get; set; }

    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
    public string Identifiant { get; set; }
    public string? FullName { get; set; }
    public string? Fonction { get; set; }
    public string? Tel { get; set; }
    public string? Note { get; set; }
    public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime RefreshTokenExpiryTime { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public Guid LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

> in the Data folder

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<PartenaireContact, IdentityRole, string>
{
    private readonly IDateTimeService _dateTime;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    private readonly ICurrentUser _currentUser;
    private readonly ISerializerService _serializer;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        IDateTimeService dateTime,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ICurrentUser currentUser,
        ISerializerService serializer) : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        _currentUser = currentUser;
        _serializer = serializer;
    }

    public DbSet<Partenaire> Partenaires { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Devise> Devises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Activite> Activites { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PartenaireActivite> PartenaireActivites { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PartenaireDetailsBancaire> PartenaireDetailsBancaires { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Trail> AuditTrails => Set<Trail>();

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var auditEntries = HandleAuditingBeforeSaveChanges();

        int result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        await HandleAuditingAfterSaveChangesAsync(auditEntries, cancellationToken);

        return result;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AppendGlobalQueryFilter<ISoftDelete>(s => s.DeletedOn == null);
        
        builder.Entity<PartenaireActivite>().HasKey(pa => new { pa.Partenaire, pa.ActiviteId });
        
        builder.Entity<PartenaireDetailsBancaire>()
            .HasOne<Partenaire>(pdb => pdb.Partenaire)
            .WithMany(p => p.PartenaireDetailsBancaires)
            .HasForeignKey(pdb => pdb.PartenaireId);

        builder.Entity<PartenaireDetailsBancaire>()
            .HasOne<Devise>(pdb => pdb.Devise)
            .WithMany(d => d.PartenaireDetailsBancaires)
            .HasForeignKey(pdb => pdb.DeviseId);

        builder.Entity<IPartenaireContact>()
            .HasOne<Partenaire>(pdb => pdb.Partenaire)
            .WithMany(p => p.PartenaireContacts)
            .HasForeignKey(pdb => pdb.PartenaireId);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

So when I try to migrate I have this error:

> The specified type
> 'ApplicationCore.Core.Entities.Base.IPartenaireContact' must be a
> non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type.

I know that I should make `IPartenaireContact` as class in my relation, but I don't like to add EntityFramework in my "Core" solution.

So any help please?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am in same situation.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use **configure entity properties using the generic version of .Property in EF Core**

Did you see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763168/common-configurations-for-entities-implementing-an-interface) answer?